# Accessing Dataproc Cluster through Apache Livy?

Tags: livy, dataproc

Can i access Dataproc cluster from Apache Livy instead of Dataproc API? If i can, Where I have to  install my apache livy server?
Currently we need to access Dataproc cluster through apache livy instead of Dataproc api. We are planning to change the api from livy to dataproc later.